# How to make Hibernate and Spring track transactions consistently?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, transactions, spring-orm

When using `TransactionTemplate` in an `Executor` thread, it appears unable to consistently find the current transaction, resulting in problems like this:

```
14:20:56.022 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG HibernateTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE
14:20:56.022 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG HibernateTransactionManager - Opened new Session [SessionImpl(1516598186<open>)] for Hibernate transaction
14:20:56.022 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG HibernateTransactionManager - Preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(1516598186<open>)]
14:20:56.023 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG HibernateTransactionManager - Exposing Hibernate transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager$$Lambda$1238/0x00000008009dfc40@5cc5f4]
14:20:56.026 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG HibernateTransactionManager - Found thread-bound Session [SessionImpl(1516598186<open>)] for Hibernate transaction
14:20:56.026 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG HibernateTransactionManager - Participating in existing transaction
14:20:56.052 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG SessionFactoryUtils - Flushing Hibernate Session on transaction synchronization
14:20:56.054 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG HibernateTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback after commit exception
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(SessionImpl.java:3478)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1394)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1389)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.flush(SessionFactoryUtils.java:113)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCommit(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:95)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:97)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:916)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:727)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionOperations.executeWithoutResult(TransactionOperations.java:67)
    at com.example.MyClass.doProcessing(MyClass.java:109)
    at com.example.MyClass.lambda$scheduleJob$4(MyClass.java:93)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
14:20:56.054 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG HibernateTransactionManager - Rolling back Hibernate transaction on Session [SessionImpl(1516598186<open>)]
14:20:56.056 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG HibernateTransactionManager - Closing Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(1516598186<open>)] after transaction
```

JPA is configured manually, because I have multiple `DataSource`s in the application.
Relevant beans:

```java
@Bean
@TelemetryDb
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean telemetryEntityManagerFactory(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @TelemetryDb DataSource dataSource
) {
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
            .packages("com.example.model.telemetry")
            .persistenceUnit("telemetry")
            .properties(getVendorProperties(dataSource))
            .jta(false)
            .build();
}

@Bean
@TelemetryDb
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public PlatformTransactionManager telemetryTransactionManager(@TelemetryDb EntityManagerFactory factory) {
    return new HibernateTransactionManager((SessionFactory) factory);
}

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackageClasses = PackageMarker.class,
        includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, value = TelemetryFilter.class),
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "telemetryEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "telemetryTransactionManager"
)
public static class Telemetry { }
```

The properties are:

```
hibernate.auto_quote_keyword=true
hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
hibernate.dialect=com.example.PostgreSQL12Dialect
```

And some code that gives the above log:

```java
@Service
@RequriedArgsConstructor
public class MyClass {

    private final MyRepository repository;

    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setTransactionManager(@TelemetryDb PlatformTransactionManager manager) {
        this.sessionFactory = ((HibernateTransactionManager) manager).getSessionFactory();
        this.transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(manager);
        this.transactionTemplate.setIsolationLevel(TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE);
    }

    public scheduleJob(long entityId) {
        Boolean submit = transactionTemplate.execute(status -> {
            MyEntity entity = repository.findById(entity).orElseThrow();
            if (entity.isProcessing()) {
                return false;
            } else {
                entity.setProcessing(true);
                return true;
            }
        });
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(submit)) {
            executor.submit(() -> doProcessing(entityId));
        }
    }

    protected void doProcessing(long entityId) {
        transactionTemplate.executeWithoutResult(status -> {
            MyEntity entity = repository.findById(entity).orElseThrow();
            entity.setBlobField(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getLobHelper().createBlob(new byte[]{});
            entity.setProcessing(false);
            status.flush();
        });
    }

}
```

Note that the usage of `TransactionTemplate` outside of the executor thread completes with no issues. Note also that the `createBlob()` and `flush()` do not complain about a missing transaction.

I assume I have missed something in the configuration, but I have been trying various permutations of it, and the `doProcessing` method, but cannot get anything to work.

---

After further debugging, it appears that the `getCurrentSession()` call causes `SpringSessionContext` to look for, and then create, a session using a `SessionFactoryImpl` as the key rather than the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` proxy.

There doesn't seem to be any way to control the construction of the context within Hibernate. I think if I could obtain the raw `SessionFactoryImpl` to pass to `HibernateTransactionManager` then that would fix it.

---

I tried that (using `EntityManagerFactory.unrwap`) but that broke a whole load of other stuff, because when Spring Data calls `createQuery` it looks for the current session using the bean proxy.

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27842

Comment: Works as expected imho. Transactions are thread bound, if you spawn a new thread, that thus isn't bounbd to the current transaction or session, and thus will fail. Another issue is that you are configuring both a `SessionFactory` **and** an `EntityManagerFactory`. Not sure why but in a recent Hibernate version the `SessionFactory` is a `EntityManagerFactory` and you can simply use that (just unwrap it). So multiple things that are, imho, wrong with your setup.

Comment: @M.Deinum this is not trying to share a transaction across threads. It's trying to use a transaction in a single thread via multiple APIs. It's also not configuring a `SessionFactory`. The `EntityManagerFactory` is a `SessionFactory`.

Comment: The `EntityManagerFactory` isn't a `SessionFactory` for Hibernate it is the other way around (the `SessionFactory` extends the `EntityManagerFactory` interface). If you are using JPA (configuring it) you should also use the `JpaTransactionManager`.  Which I suspect is the main issue here, using the wrong tx manager for the technology used.

Comment: @M.Deinum no, there is no configuration of a separate `SessionFactory`. Look at the code above. I'll change it to an explicit cast if that makes it clearer. Whichever transaction manager is used also makes no difference. I've already debugged all this and know exactly what's happening. See the answer.

Comment: Either my English sucks or your reading? I nowhere said you are configuring a `SessionFactory`. I'm only explaining that you should be using the proper technologies together and not mix. If you configure JPA, use the JPA transaction manager, if you then want to use the underlying `SessionFactory` or `Session` just use the `unwrap` method if you must (I would suggest to unwrap the `Entitymanager` to a `Session` but alas).

Comment: @M.Deinum "you are configuring both a `SessionFactory` **and** an `EntityManagerFactory`"

Comment: @M.Deinum none of your suggestions worked. As the question says, I already tried them.

Comment: Then I wonder why they worked for me, but apparently I'm doing it wrong then. I know that things broke due to changes in Hibernate suddenly making the `SessionFactory` an `EntityManagerFactory` in version 5.3 (IIRC) but after working with that things just worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that [`SpringSessionContext` doesn't work as intended](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27842). Either there was a change in Hibernate and/or there wasn't sufficient integration testing.

There is a workaround. Ignore `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` and use the `TransactionSynchronizationManager` directly:

```java
@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "telemetry")
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

private @NonNull Session getCurrentSession() {
    Object resource = TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(entityManagerFactory);
    if (resource == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No current transaction");
    }
    return ((SessionHolder) resource).getSession();
}
```

That only works within an existing session. More code would be required to create a new one to match the full behaviour.

Unsetting `hibernate.current_session_context_class` ensures you will always get an exception when trying to use the incompatible interface, rather than getting surprise extra sessions.

---

Another (simpler) workaround:

```java
@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "telemetry")
private EntityManager entityManager;

private @NonNull Session getCurrentSession() {
    return entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
}
```

Comment: An additional note that `LobHelper` isn't always necessary. You can use [`new SerialBlob(bytes[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql.rowset/javax/sql/rowset/serial/SerialBlob.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte[])) instead.